# Moodle course completion report - sql

Tags: sql, moodle

Just wondering if anyone has the SQL code for the course completion report in moodle? currently using Moodle 3.7.

Cheers

Comment: I recommend adding more to your question, what have you tried and what you need. The question does not have enough information to go on.

Comment: and a url for the course completion report